Azure Pipeline iOS Build fails in MSBuild@1:The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild' failed with exit code 1
So I have a running Azure Devops Pipeline for my iOS build that is running fine without issues until today. I get error in MSBuild@1: Build iOS Project
##[error]Error: The process '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild' failed with exit code 1

Please see the yml script below:
variables:  
  NugetVersion: 6.9.1
  BuildConfiguration: Release
  RestoreSolution: src/MyApp.Core.sln
  MONO_VERSION: 6_12_0
  XCODE_VERSION: 13.2.1
  MACOS_VERSION: macOS-11
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
#Source: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md#xamarin
#Update macOS 10.15: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/5583

- job: build_macos
  displayName: Build macOS Library
  pool:
      vmImage: $(MACOS_VERSION)
      
  steps:
  # make sure to select the correct Xamarin and mono
  - bash: sudo $AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY/scripts/select-xamarin-sdk.sh $(MONO_VERSION)
    displayName: Switch to the latest Xamarin SDK
    
  - bash: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=MD_APPLE_SDK_ROOT;]'/Applications/Xcode_$(XCODE_VERSION).app;sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_$(XCODE_VERSION).app/Contents/Developer
    displayName: Switch to the latest Xcode

  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    displayName: 'Use NuGet $(NugetVersion)'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: $(NugetVersion)

  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'NuGet restore'
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: $(RestoreSolution)

  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: 'Build iOS Project'
    inputs:
      solution: src/MyApp.iOS/MyApp.iOS.csproj
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'src/MyApp.iOS/bin/Release/xamarin.ios10/'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/lib/xamarin.ios10/'

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
    inputs:
      artifactName: MyAppArtifactStagingDirectory
      pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

I tried to update the following:

Nuget version to 6.10.0
Mono version to 6.12.0.206
MacOS version to macOS-14
Xcode version to 15.0.1

but I just encountered additional issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You know that Xamarin bits reached end of life, right? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/xamarin

Yes, though we still need to fix some bugs for our BAU while migrating our app in .NET Maui. What I know is that it MS stops supporting Xamarin, but it would not immediately put everything down..


Can you build your project on your local machine successfully? If it works locally, set up a self-hosted on your local machine and run your pipeline using it. Then the pipeline should work. If it doesn't work locally, what changes have you made? 2. Please add a variable system.debug and set the value to true. Then trigger the pipeline to check if there is any detailed error message.


I was able to fix the issue thanks to system.debug. Apparently I had a code in my project that was causing error CS1525, which just required a simple refactoring. It was building fine in my Visual Studio, but the Microsoft Hosted agent found the error.

Hi @rog, it's great to know your issue has been resolved. To help others who may have the similar issue and make the solution clearer, it's suggested that you could share your root cause and solution below. Thanks!
